# Multiple MAC addresses for the same device?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, mac-address

My BT Broadband router is showing up a different MAC address for two of my devices as shown below. Is this normal?

## LAPTOP

MAC address shown by BT Hub: 02:0F:B5:BA:A0:87
MAC address shown in Command Prompt: 80-56-F2-BA-A0-87

## Galaxy Tablet

MAC address shown by BT Hub: 02:0F:B5:9A:A8:25
MAC address shown in tablet settings: 3C:DC:BC:9A:A8:25

Answer (score 1):

The MAC address belongs to Netgear. My guess is that you're using a Wi-Fi "extender" which itself connects wirelessly to the BT Hub as if it were a regular Wi-Fi client. And like any other Wi-Fi client, your extender is only allowed to use *one* MAC address within its connection to the BT Hub (the Wi-Fi standard doesn't allow it to act as a full bridge).

So whenever your extender receives packets from the laptop's or tablet's original MAC address, it has to replace it with *its own* MAC address before forwarding those packets to the BT Hub. (It does the opposite when receiving packets back.) Essentially the extender implements MAC-layer NAT.

To avoid this, you would need to use wired access points which connect to the router over Ethernet. (Similarly, power-line bridges and purpose built "mesh" extenders also won't have this problem – as long as their final connection to the BT Hub is over Ethernet.)

Comment: That is indeed what the Netgear Wi-Fi extender that I have does.

Comment: Indeed both were connected to the WiFi extender at the same time. The pattern is that the last 6 characters of the MAC address remain the same while the first 6 are changed. Is that how Netgear does it?